# How to change the color of chart titles

Tags: android, achartengine

Is there a way to change the color of chart titles (x-axis, y-axis, and chart heading) in `aChartEngine`? I changed my background to black, but can't get these labels to display, since they are also black.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Axis titles are changed using the `renderer.setLabelsColor(Color);` command. I'm not sure about the title, it may be changed using the same command. In case you'd like to change the data values on the axes, the `renderer.setXLabelsColor(Color);` and   `renderer.setYLabelsColor(scale, Color);` commands will do that for you.

If you go to achartengine's website, you can download the javadoc as a zip file, extract it, then view it in your browser. It's got a decent amount of documentation on there to find what you need normally =)

Comment: Thanks Matt, however these methods only seem to affect the colours of the axis value labels, not the axis titles.

Comment: Okay, just done a bit of testing, and the command to change the axis titles is `setLabelsColor` - I've edited my original answer to reflect this

Comment: Turns out I had a second 'setLabelsColor(Color)' call in my code which I did not originally see.. works great now, thanks!